# Constructor bind this in async function not working?

Tags: javascript, reactjs

I bind my function in constructor but its return me nothing ? what did i do wrong ? i want to access my class function inside the async function

```js
class UploadAvatar extends React.Component {

    constructor(props) {
      super(props);
      this.changeAvatar = this.changeAvatar.bind(this);
    }

  changeAvatar() {

    console.log('changeavt')


  }
    async function uploadImageAsync(uri) {

      var reader = new FileReader();
      reader.readAsDataURL(blob);
      reader.onloadend = function() {
        var base64data = reader.result;
        // this.changeAvatar(base64data)
        console.log(this)
      }
    }
}
```

Comment: There is no `changeAvatar` in the code you posted. The "loadend" function will be invoked with a different `this` in any case, so binding won't make any difference. You can save `this` in a separate local variable *outside* the handler and use that to get to the method.

Comment: how do i do that

Comment: `let uploader = this;` and then inside the handler `uploader.changeAvatar(base64data);`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

1. Remove `function` keyword from your class method.
2. Bind your `uploadImageAsync` with this

```
class UploadAvatar extends React.Component {
  constructor(props) {
    super(props);
    this.changeAvatar = this.changeAvatar.bind(this);
    // bind this 
    this.uploadImageAsync = this.uploadImageAsync.bind(this);
  }

  changeAvatar() {
    console.log("changeavt");
  }

  // remove `function` keyword
  async uploadImageAsync(uri) {
    var reader = new FileReader();
    reader.readAsDataURL(blob);
    reader.onloadend = function() {
      var base64data = reader.result;
      // this.changeAvatar(base64data)
      console.log(this);
    };
  }
}
```